# Show that the volume of $B_4$ is equal $2\int_{B_3} \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} dxdydz$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B_4$ be the closed ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $B_3$ the analogous ball at $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that the volume of $B_4$ is equal

$2\int_{B_3} \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} dxdydz$

any tips for doing this construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the one dimension less case If $x^2+y^2+z^2=1 $is the sphere $B_3$ of unit radius in $R^3$ then the function $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is the height of the surface(upper hemisphere) above the x-y plane.

And for z=0 (the projection on the x-y plane of the surface i.e. upper hemisphere) is simply $B_2$ and so

$\int_{B_2} \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)} dxdy$ is simply the volume of the upper hemisphere which leads to the volume of $B_3$ being $2\int_{B_2} \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)} $

If we reproduce this procedure we have $x^2+y^2+z^2 +w^2=1$ who's projection in the x-y-z space is the ball $B_3$ which leads to your required construction analogously.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!